# HTML/Canvas Recording not working on Firefox 36.0.4

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas, recording

I'm getting the following error when I'm running the **[RecordRTC Canvas/HTML Recorder](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/Canvas-Recording/)** demo.

On Firefox Error Console:

> Error: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
>   Source File: chrome:// web-developer /content/overlay/javascript/overlay.js
>   Line: 7333
>
> Error: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount
>   Source File: https:// cdn.webrtc-experiment.com / screenshot.js
>   Line: 10

After recording I'm getting a note on the player saying "Videos can't played because the file is corrupt"

Can someone please help me how to fix the firefox issue? Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot for "Videos can't played because the file is corrupt" on firefox]

Comment: Here is the source code from github ==> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/master/RecordRTC/Canvas-Recording/index.html